# How do you build a clientaccesspolicy.xml for this API?

Tags: silverlight, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I have a RESTlike API that I want to access from Silverlight. It needs to support the following:

- All requests are made over SSL
- Allow GET, POST, PUT, DELETE (or just any)
- Allow any request headers
- Allow requests from any host

Pretty much wide open. I'm a little confused by the docs so does anyone have an example of what it might look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something wide-open but only allowing https and not http would look something like this and would need to be named **clientaccesspolicy.xml** and placed in the web root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*" http-methods="*">
        <domain uri="https://*" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

If you want to allow both http and https access you need to explicitly list both of them under the allow-from node as it is opt-in and a simple * wildcard will not work for SSL.

**Edit:** Added `http-methods="*"` per John's comment to allow methods other than GET and POST.

Comment: Do you know if I need to add http-methods="*" to the allow-from element?

Comment: Hey John, you are right. If you don't add the http-methods="*" you are only allowing GET and POST... that was an oversight on my part. I'll update my answer. Found the info here if you are curious: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MSDN Documentation on the matter: [Making a Service Available Across Domain Boundaries.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Some hints on where to get started:

- Get [Tim Heuer's Cross Domain helpers](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/help/SilverlightSpy/html/05f52640-39b1-414c-9c45-cf0356fa89a6.htm)
- Use [Silverlight Spy's Cross-domain Access Policy Validator](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/help/SilverlightSpy/html/05f52640-39b1-414c-9c45-cf0356fa89a6.htm) if you get stuck: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx